# Use xarray to interpolate one netCDF to match resolution of another netCDF

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have 2 netCDFs with different resolutions (one is 1 degree and another is 0.25 degree). How can I convert the resolution of the 1 degree netCDF to 0.25 degree by using some xarray interpolation method (I do not want to fill in with NaNs). I looked at using interp_like but it seems to fill in using NaNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [xESMF](https://xesmf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for Python and xarray, it is really simple. The function [regridder](https://xesmf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_api.html#regridder) is what you are looking for (see also [this example](https://xesmf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Rectilinear_grid.html) on the website). To give you another example, this is a [blog post](http://www.matteodefelice.name/post/c3s-multimodel/) I wrote time ago which you might find useful.

Comment: I think so, I would suggest using Anaconda.